# How do apps give away Facebook Credits?

Tags: facebook-credits, credits

I see apps and websites that give away Facebook Credits in sweepstakes, and am curious about the mechanics.  I haven't seen anything in the Facebook documentation about how to generate Facebook Credits for a user.  Have I missed something?  Or are developers simply buying Facebook gift cards and sending them to the winners?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!